# What's a good free defragmenting tool for a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, defragment

I have a Windows XP VirtualPC machine with a virtual hard disk. It's a dynamic disk, which means it expands as needed.

Right now it's about 13.8GB, mostly because I've done a bunch of stuff to it.

There's really only about 9GB of stuff on there, less when I clean it up a bit more.

I tried to defragment the disk using the built-in defragmenter for XP and it shows an enormous gap in the layout of the disk - probably all that stuff I removed.

However, after defragmenting the giant gap is still there, although obviously some defragmenting did occur.

My thinking is - if I could get this disk to really defragment completely then I could compact the image and get that filesize back. And since the end goal is to distribute this to some coworkers, that would be a big plus.

So - are there any free defragmenting tools which do a thorough job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm partial to [jkdefrag](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/) to do my defragging work.  I've never used it in a VM for exactly what you want to do, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff blogged about making [Smaller Virtual Machines](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000639.html) and suggested using Whitney Defrag. In the comments John Mitchell suggested using SDelete, (to write zeros in the empty space to aid compression), as a free alternative to what Jeff recommends in his step 5.

Answer (score 0):

The best windows defrag tool I have used is Diskeeper.  It isn't cheap but it does the job well.

http://www.diskeeper.com/

They have versions specifically for virtual environments but I have only used the stand alone versions.